# How to Get Data From Database Using Select Option in PHP?

Tags: php, html-select

I'll do to get data from database using select option, but there is nothing to show any output... anyone can find the problem what is the problem,either my code or either we adopt wrong technique?
here is my code below
`

```
            <div class="heading" style="margin-bottom:10px; float:left; color:black;">Select Records</div>
            <div style="float:right; color:black;">
                <form >
                <select  name="session" >
                <option value='Null'><b>Select Session</b></option>             
                <?php
                $status_on = 'no';
                            $query1 = "select * from sessions where 
                          status='$status_on'";

                            $run = mysqli_query($con,$query1);
                            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run)){                   
                            $id = $row['session_id'];
                            $p_id = $row['program_id'];
                            $session_name  = $row['session_name'];
                            echo "      
                            <option value='$id'><b>$session_name</b></option>";

                        }
                            ?>          

                </select>       
                <input type="submit" value="go"  />
                <div style="color:red;"> 
                    <?php 
                        if(isset($_GET['go'])){

                        $session = $_GET['session'];

                            $sql = "select * from students where session_id like'%$session%'";
                          //$sql = "select * from students where session_id='$session%'";
                            // also tried

                            $run = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run)){

                                $s_name = $row['s_name'];



                    ?>
                        <table> 
                            <tr> 
                            <td><?php echo $s_name;?></td>
                            </tr>
                                    <?php }?>
                                    <?php }?>
                        </table>
                </div>
                </form>

            </div>

            <?php include("footer.php");?>
```

Comment: What do you aspect?

Comment: what you get when you run this query in your database? `select * from sessions where status='no'`

Comment: @Mohammad dear nothing to get when run this query

Comment: if you have no data in the database how can you expect it to show on the screen?

Comment: but i have data

Comment: @Mohsin the problem is with your query !! share an example representing your table please

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually just `name="go"` was missing.

**Wrong:**

```
<input type="submit" value="go">
```

**Correct:**

```
<input type="submit" value="go" name="go">
```

Now everything is okay.

Answer (score 0):

Made correction to output table:

```
            <?php 
                if(isset($_GET['go'])){

                $session = $_GET['session'];

                    $sql = "select * from students where session_id like'%$session%'";
                  //$sql = "select * from students where session_id='$session%'";
                    // also tried

                    $run = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
            ?>
                <table>
            <?
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run)){

                        $s_name = $row['s_name'];



            ?>
                    <tr> 
                    <td><?php echo $s_name;?></td>
                    </tr>
                            <?php }?>
                </table>
                            <?php }?>
```

Comment: check you querys in phpMyAdmin

Comment: how to check in phpMyAdmin? i have data in students also , like select session data from database